# Openfire http-bind

Tags: xmpp, openfire

How can we connect to Openfire using secured http-bind (port 7443 by default)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the Openfire admin console you will need to enable http-bind in order to utilize it. At this point you can also configure the port which it runs under.

Answer (score 5):

You need a client that support Bosh with https. Pidgin is one such client.

I am able to connect using pidgin and setting the bosh path as https://hostname:7443/http-bind

Comment: I am trying to connect to Openfire using Pidgin with the url you mention above but am receiving the message 'Lost connection with server: Bad file descriptor', could this be a certificate error.  I am using a self-signed certificate.

Comment: yes it is possible that it is a certificate error. I have not used pidgin for a while so cannot be sure.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable the http-binding from Server-> Server settings -> HTTP Binding 
[image]